# How can I customize the line highlight color in Vim CtrlP?

Tags: vim, colors, ctrlp

When I'm using the Vim plugin [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) I have a hard time seeing which file is being highlighted as the current file I might open. I want the highlight line to be bright and vivid.

I could change the color of my CursorLine setting but I don't want it to change everywhere. When I'm normally editing files I want my highlight cursor line to be a subtle background-ish color.

How can I change the color of only the highlight line in the CtrlP file selection buffer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got a lead on a fix in this [GitHub issue asking a similar question](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/issues/337).

CtrlP offers a setting called `ctrlp_buffer_func` that lets you set a function to call every time CtrlP is loaded and when it exits. In my .vimrc file, I just set the highlight color to a bright and vivid color on CtrlP load, and then set it back to my default when I exit CtrlP.

```
let g:ctrlp_buffer_func = { 'enter': 'BrightHighlightOn', 'exit':  'BrightHighlightOff', }

function BrightHighlightOn()
  hi CursorLine guibg=darkred
endfunction

function BrightHighlightOff()
  hi CursorLine guibg=#191919
endfunction
```